# MapStruct initialize variable with enum

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have this enum:

```
@Getter
public enum Error
{
    EMAIL( "Invalid email" ),
    GROUP( "Invalid group" ),
    NONE( "" );

    private final String errorMessage;

    Error( String errorMessage )
    {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

And I have this class:

```
@Value
public class User {
    private Error error;
}
```

And them I have a mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserModelToUser
{
    User map( UserModel userModel );
}
```

My idea was to initialize the error with the value of the enum Error.NONE but I have no idea   how to accomplish that with the `@Mapping` or other way.

The enum and the class are in different packages otherwise I could use something like this:

```
@Mapping( target = "error", expression = "java( Error.NONE )" )
```

And I can't move out of that package.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need just write full name of enum.
For example:

```
    @Mapping( target = "error", expression = "java( com.somepackage.somesubpackage.Error.NONE )" )
    User map(UserModel userModel );
```

Comment: Not sure how I didn't thought of this. Thanks